# Is there something like a filterIndex?

Tags: javascript

So I am looking for a function like [Array.prototype.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) which returns an array of indexes. Like `Array.prototype.find` and `Array.prototype.filter` return one item and an array of items respectively. I was looking at MDN but couldn't find anything suitable.

I would like to stay compatible with future versions of javascript, is there something planned to be added?

Comment: you return the indices after filtering, starting from `0` to `length  - 1`. is this the wanted result, or do you like to get the original indices.?

Comment: @NinaScholz should work just like findIndex

Comment: @Keith findIndex just returns the first result

Comment: Oh, I see, your wanting to return an array as result..

Comment: "*I would like to stay compatible with future versions of javascript*" - then don't install anything on `Array.prototype` but use a static function that takes the array as an argument

Comment: @Bergi I'd rather use a polyfill if there is already a spec out there

Comment: @Julius Sure, but I'm not aware of anything. The use case is rather rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the most suitable builtin method would be `flatMap` which you can use for maybe-mapping an array:

```
['a', 'c', 'a', 'b'].flatMap((v, i) => v == 'a' ? [i] : [])
```

I am not aware of any proposal to add such a functionality. If you need this more often, you can write your own helper function:

```
function findIndices(array, callback, ctx) {
    const res = [];
    for (let i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        if (callback.call(ctx, array[i], i, array))
            res.push(i);
    return res;
}
```

```
findIndices(['a', 'c', 'a', 'b'], v => v == 'a')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map the indices along with the value and get a callback and return an array of indices.

```js
Array.prototype.filterIndex = function (cb) {
    return this
        .map((o, i) => [o, i])
        .filter(([o]) => cb(o))
        .map(([, i]) => i);
};

console.log(['a', 'b', 'a'].filterIndex(v => v === 'a'));
```

Comment: Thanks Nina! That's a great solution. I was especially interested to know whether there is anything built in, or anything planned to be built in.

Comment: there is no built in, and about a planned one, i don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use existing method `Array.prototype.reduce`

```js
let out = ['a','b','a'].reduce((acc, curr, i) => (curr === 'a' && acc.push(i), acc), []); 
console.log(out)
```

Comment: Your tenery can be removed here -> `(curr === 'a' && acc.push(i), acc)`

Comment: Why not just write proper statements instead of using conditional and comma operators?

Answer (score 0):

You can even use `.map`

```js
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'a'];
let data = array1.map((data,index) => data == "a" ? index : []).join('').split('')
console.log(data)
```

You can even just return the index by doing a `forEach` and return the index if the callback matches.

```js
Array.prototype.filterIndex = function(cb) {
  let arr = [];
  this.forEach((a, index) => {
    if (cb(a)) arr.push(index)
  })
  return arr
}
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'a'];

let data = array1.filterIndex((data) => data == "a")
console.log(data)
```